# The proportions of those arrangements of the numerals 1,2,...,9 in which all the multiples of 3 appears consecutively is

Tags: number-theory

The multiples of 3 appears in 3! Ways consecutively in 7 different places while the remaining numbers appears in 6! Ways therefore we have 7*3!*6! Ways of arranging the numbers. Now the proportion of the arrangement = (7*3!*6!)/9!=1/12

Comment: The question is asking in how many ways can you write a nine-digit number, where each digit is a unique one from $1,2,...,9$, in which $3,6,9$ (not necessarily in that order) appear right next to each other. (Specifically it wants the proportion/fraction of such arrangements overall, but answering the former question makes the remainder quite simple.)

Comment: @MahaShri Don't forget to account for how many possible places the multiples of $3$ may start at.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @MahaShri I assume your comment above was meant for at least me, if not also to Evee Trainer. If so, then you're welcome. I believe your updated answer is now correct. Also, note I didn't get any notice regarding your comment. If you wish to have somebody notified, you usually need to use '@' followed by the first letter or two of the name, then to avoid typing the whole name, you can just choose the appropriate name (if more than one is shown) from the tooltip which is shown.